# Имя функции в макросе

Tags: c

Как в макросе получить имя функции (строчное значение), внутри которой макрос был использован?

```
#define MACRO() ...

void f1() {
     MACRO() // Здесь "f1"
}

void f2() {
     MACRO() // Здесь "f2"
}
```

Я что-то вроде когда-то видел, но забыл где (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть макрос `__FUNCTION__`, который содержит имя функции в строковом виде так, как оно прописано в исходном коде. И MS VC, и GCC его поддерживают. Если нужно печать имя функции в лог, делается так:

```
#define PRINT_NAME() printf("Function %s", __FUNCTION__)

voif func() {
    PRINT_NAME();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define  MACRO(name) ...

void f1()
{
    MACRO("f1");
}
```

знаю, что глупо, но тоже вариант =)

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант не подойдет. Нужно, чтобы макрос сам определил имя функции, из которой он вызван. Иначе трудоемкость использования сильно возрастет: нужно будет в каждом вызове прописывать имя функции.